# concatenate a string to a variable chr

Tags: r, concatenation, paste, string-concatenation

I am trying to generate a web adress in R. I have a fix string "http://mutationassessor.org/?cm=var&var=" and I want append to it a particular character string.

I have tried different solutions, but I fail somewhere.

```
mydata$mutationassessorquery  <- paste(mydata$chromosome, mydata$position,     mydata$reference_allele, mydata$alternate_allele, sep = ",")
mydata$mutationassessorurl  <- "http://mutationassessor.org/?cm=var&var="
mydata$mutationassessorurl <- paste(mydata$mutationassessorurl, mydata$mutationassessorquery)

str(mydata$mutationassessorurl)
chr [1:27566] "http://mutationassessor.org/?cm=var&var=" "http://mutationassessor.org/?cm=var&var=" ...

str(mydata$mutationassessorquery)
chr [1:27566] "1,2493198,T,TC" "1,9782556,C,T" "1,120539331,C,T" "1,120611964,G,C" "1,206669465,C,T" ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Typo on third line you have "<" instead of "<-"

Comment: you might need to add `sep=""` when pasting the url with the query. But other than that you don't actually say what the problem is and what the expected result should be.